# Testing drag-and-drop with Selenium 2 on Telerik controls

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, telerik

I need to automate drag and drop functionality with Telerik controls, I currently use WatiN for my automation (see related quesiton [Testing drag-and-drop with Watin on Telerik controls](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/549/testing-drag-and-drop-with-watin-on-telerik-controls)
. I am considering if WatiN can't do it, will I able to test drag and drop will if I change to use Selenium 2 instead.

Can this (drag and drop testing in a web applicaiton) be easily achieved with Selenium2 (in C#), ideally without injecting javascript into the application being teseted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I'm not certain if these mechanisms will specifically work with the Telerik controls (I know it works with jQuery), there are a couple of ways to do this. You can use `IRenderedWebElement.DragAndDropOn()`, but this method is deprecated. The newer way, which isn't available in a released binary form yet, but is checked into the source tree and will be released in the next binary, is to use the `Actions` class to create the drag-and-drop action. Your code would look something like the following:

```
public void DragAndDropExample()
{
    // driver is an instance of IWebDriver; 
    // elementToDrag and targetElement are instances of IWebElement
    Actions actionsProvider = new Actions(driver);
    actionsProvider.DragAndDrop(elementToDrag, targetElement).Perform();
}
```

You can also use the `DragAndDropToOffset()` method if you want to drag an element to an arbitrary screen location.

Comment: Excellent! This worked for me. Until the recent versions of the FirefoxDriver I had to try and do it with the legacy Selenium driver and mouseDown/mouseMove commands. I am using the offset method now (note the casing is wrong in the sample above - but an IDE editor should be enough to help assist)